# 'Arts and crafts'-definition

Tags: vocabulary

I'm a bit confused about the definition of '**arts and crafts'.**

- Is it the same as '**handicrafts**'?
- Does it refer to ***objects*** made in this way or the ***technique*** itself?

Could you give me an example sentence for this phrase?

Comment: "Arts and Crafts" was the name of an artistic movement in mid-19th century Britain. Are you asking about that?

Comment: As Michael has pointed out, it depends on the context - there are a few different way to use the phrase. Where did you encounter  “arts and crafts” ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the **crafts** part of **arts and crafts** is definitely the same as **handicrafts**, while the **arts** part often encompasses more "classical" techniques like painting or sculpture (especially sculpture with clay).  What makes **arts and crafts** different from **fine art** is that the people making it are almost always amateur or untrained artists who have not have formal training at a dedicated art school.

The phrase itself has a number of uses:

As an **activity**:

> On rainy days, my kids like to keep themselves busy with **arts and crafts**.
>
> The retirement home uses **arts and crafts** as a form of therapy.

To describe the **objects** created by the activity:

> The museum displays **arts and crafts** typical to the region.
>
> She saved all of the **arts and crafts** her kids had made in at summer camp over the years.

With capital letters, the [**Arts and Crafts movement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arts_and_Crafts_movement) was a set of styles in design, art, and architecture that was popular during the years 1880 through 1920.